# What is the best way to see how Dataflow is doing fusion optimization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to optimize a pipeline that pulls messages from PubSubIO and sends those messages to a 3rd party API. One interesting observation I have is that if I put a `GroupBy` and a "Degroup" transform after the `PubSubIO.read`, the throughput of pipeline increased significantly. I added the `GroupBy` just to prevent fusion optimization, and now I wonder how exactly the transform being merged in a given pipeline.

What is the best way to find out how a pipeline looks like after the fusion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access your optimized graph and fused stages by either calling [project.locations.jobs.get](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.jobs/get) or via gcloud by running the following command:

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs describe --full $JOB_ID --format json
```

From the output of the response, the fused stages will be described under the [ExecutionStageSummary](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#executionstagesummary) object within the [ComponentTransform](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#Job.ComponentTransform) array. Below is an example output from the [Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloudpubsubtobigquery) Google-provided template. In this case, we can see the graph was fused into 3 steps largely delineated by the `Reshuffle` step within the [BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html) sink:

1. S03 - All transforms **before** the `Reshuffle` in `WriteSuccessfulRecords` and `WriteFailedRecords`
2. S02 - All transforms **after** the `Reshuffle` in `WriteSuccessfulRecords`
3. S01 - All transforms **after** the `Reshuffle` in `WriteFailedRecords`

[Full Output](https://gist.github.com/ryanmcdowell/34cd1670e0b1c386b555d6ac488e14aa)

[image: Job Description]

Since the job description is pretty verbose, you may consider piping the output to `jq` to easily extract the relevant bits in a one-line command such as the below:

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs describe --full $JOB_ID --format json | jq '.pipelineDescription.executionPipelineStage[] | {"stage_id": .id, "stage_name": .name, "fused_steps": .componentTransform }'
```

Answer (score 0):

These days you can see which stages of the pipeline have been fused by looking in the Dataflow UI under the Execution Details tab. For example:

[image]

In this example F7 and F6 are the two fused stages